The result of the bitwise operation exceeds the maximum possible value
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COUNTS 1000000

int f2() 
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1) 
    {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        return 1;
    }
    
    srand(ts.tv_nsec);

    int num;
    do
    {
        num = (int)((double) (rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0))*5) + 1;
    } while (num == 3);

    return (num > 3) ? 1 : 0;
}


int f3()
{
    printf("a. %d\n",(f2()<<2 + f2()<<1 + f2()));
    printf("b. %d\n",((int)(f2()<<2) + (int)(f2()<<1) + (int)f2()));
    return ((int)(f2()<<2) + (int)(f2()<<1) + (int)f2());
    // return (f2()<<2 + f2()<<1 + f2());
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNTS; i++)
    {
        f3();
    }

    return 0;
}

When I run the program above, it will print
a. 8
b. 3
a. 0
b. 6
a. 16
b. 1
a. 16
b. 1
a. 0
b. 6
a. 0
b. 6
a. 32
b. 0
a. 32
b. 4
a. 32
b. 6
a. 0
b. 0
a. 16
b. 7
a. 16
b. 5
a. 0
b. 4
a. 8
b. 6
a. 8
b. 1
a. 32
b. 3
a. 16
b. 7
a. 0
b. 7
a. 0
b. 2
a. 16
b. 2
a. 32
b. 6
a. 0
b. 6
a. 0
b. 3
a. 0
b. 1
a. 8
b. 4
a. 0
b. 2
a. 16
b. 4

When I run the above program, the print is as follows. I ensure that the f2 function returns only 0 and 1, and after calling the f2 function, perform bitwise operations. Why does the first printf print 16 and 32, even if f2 returns 1 for all, the maximum value should only be 7? The return value of the second printf looks correct. Why is this
The platform I am on is Ubuntu 20.04
I want to know if such a result has occurred

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

@user28857187 By the way this statement return (num > 3) ? 1 : 0; can be written simpler like return num > 3;

Tip: You can use | instead of + here.

Tip: Not an issue in your program, but it's a good habit to shift unsigned values instead of signed values. Less issues that way.

A weird question. You output a. and b. with parentheses and still have a question...

Note that in a single call to f3(), your code calls f2() and hence srand() 9 times, and each call to f2() could return a different value.  The sequencing of the calls in the printf() statements and the return statement is indeterminate, too.  And there's the precedence problem diagnosed in the answers, too.  The value printed with a. will usually be different from the value printed with b. and both will probably be different from the value returned from f3().

Note that to get an approximately uniform sequence of pseudo-random numbers, you should seed the PRNG just once, before retrieving the first number.  Seeding it before every draw undercuts the objective.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

If you turn warnings on, the compiler will tell you (at least mine does):
$ gcc -Wall 1.c
1.c: In function ‘f3’:
1.c:31:31: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘<<’ [-Wparentheses]
     printf("a. %d\n",(f2()<<2 + f2()<<1 + f2()));
                             ~~^~~~~~
1.c:31:41: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘<<’ [-Wparentheses]
     printf("a. %d\n",(f2()<<2 + f2()<<1 + f2()));
                                       ~~^~~~~~

It's a precedence problem! The addition happens before the bit shift. Use parentheses to fix it.
-    printf("a. %d\n",(f2()<<2 + f2()<<1 + f2()));
+    printf("a. %d\n",((f2()<<2) + (f2()<<1) + f2()));


Because shift operators and arithmetic operators have different precedence, this precedence is used if no parentheses are specified. In fact in the printf() .b the values ​​you can observe are in the range [0,7].
This is a reference on the precedence given to operators.
I recommend that you enable all compiler warnings and errors and use a debugger to step through your code.
A playground example with explicit parentheses. This is your code slightly modified to allow you to compare the two printf()s on the same inputs, and see how the compiler groups the operands.
The interested code:
int f3()
{
    int v1 = f2(), v2 = f2(), v3 = f2();
    printf("a. %d %d\n", v1 << 2 + v2 << 1 + v3,   // as you wrote
            v1 << (2 + v2) << (1 + v3));           // how the compiler interprets it
    printf("b. %d\n", (v1 << 2) + (v2 << 1) + v3); // the rest of your code
    return ((v1 << 2) + (v2 << 1) + v3);
}


When you get unexpected behavior, the first thing you need to do is make the code output reproducible. In this case you should eliminate rand(), which generates pseudorandom numbers, to be able to find the problem, or change its usage, as in the following code.

What is purpose of all those (int)?

@3CxEZiVlQ You're asking a question about the Question's code, but you placed it as a reply to one of the Answers.

@3CxEZiVlQ is only the requester's code, adjusted to explicitly show the compiler/language standard operators precedence, using parentheses. Function call are replaced with v1..v3 to make results comparable on same inputs. But I agree with you that removing casts would make the code cleaner.

Sidenote: This code calls f2 3 times while the code in the question calls it 9 times.
